# The task with the name "Back Up Database Task" ... is not registered for use on this computer

Tags: sql-server, backup

I can't edit "Back Up Database Task", please help me. Sorry, I don't speak English very well.

> The task with the name "Back Up Database Task" and the creation name "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.DbMaintenanceBackupTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.MaintenancePlanTasks, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" is not registered for use on this computer.
>   Contact Information:
>   Back Up Database Task

[[image: Error show]]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SSMS 17, You can get it from provided URL:

[Download SQL Server Management Studio 17.9.1](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2043154)

Thank You

Comment: The correct way to approach "there's a character limit" is to put *useful content* in there. Not to leave snark. All in all, not a great way to make a "first impression" here on SO.

Comment: @Mer Thank You Mer Yes using SQL Management Studio 17.9 Did Solve Problem
Thank You <3